# How can remove the spikes in common mode rail?

Tags: mosfet, analog, design, transceiver, common-mode

Following is the circuit I am working with.
[image]

Intended output across R7 is (60  Ohm resistor) is:

- More than 2 mA current for logic high (5 V) input V1
- Less than 0.1 mA for logic low (0 V) input V1

Another key point is, output should have a common mode voltage of 2.5 V

Following is the characteristics of input and output waveform
[image]

Color code: Green (Input), Blue (Output)

Output voltage is taken with respect to ground. Ideally there should be output voltage around the 2.5V common mode voltage and there should be no such spikes as I have highlighted in the brown circles.

Questions:

1) Why there is spikes in the output?

2) How this spikes can be removed?

Comment: Spikes are causes by the differences in switching times of the transistor paths..... As for how to fix it.... I really don't see how this will work as drawn so no answer to that bit.

Comment: What's common mode about it?

Comment: @Trevor, basic working is logic high will turn on both FETs (M2 and M4) and 2.4mA current will be flown through the output resistor (R7) and 2.5V is provided for common mode voltage

Comment: @winny, output should swing around +2.5V

Comment: That's fine, but logic low ZERO current flows....

Comment: @Trevor, logic ZERO current is fine with me. As long as logic ZERO current is in uA range, I am fine with it.

Comment: Still not common mode.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @winny,In my knowledge, this is how the common mode voltage need to be. I don't understand how this is not common mode?

Answer (score 2):

Spikes are caused by a race between the relative turn on times of the MOSFETS. You need a single transistor.

This circuit should work. M1 just shorts out the load resistor when the input is low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feQyxD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: simulated the circuit with LTSpice but the output voltage is not aperfect square wave. I was expecting a square wave at the output but it seems more curved at the peeks

Comment: @vt673 no such thing as a prefect square wave, and yes the capacitance of the mosfet will tend to round things off.

Comment: ,Can we reduce the capacitive effect. ( I understand that there is no such perfect square wave is practically possible, trying to make the output as close as possible to the idle one) :-)

Comment: @vt673 reducing the capacitance with a different mosfet is about your only choice.

Comment: @vt673 it would really help if you explained what this is for....

Comment: I was checking the practical feasibility of AVC-LAN transceiver discrete solution. Following is the link for your reference.[link](https://elinux.org/AVC-LAN#Hardware)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67902/discussion-between-vt673-and-trevor).